# Browserify bundled node js file in chrome extension throws the following error.

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm fairly new to javascript, I'm trying to build a chrome extension scraper using node and html, here's part of the code for the javascript file

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var href;
var text;

request("http://URL", function (error, response, html) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
$("a.hp-article-link").each(function(i, element){

    text = $(this).text(); 
    href = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(text);
    console.log(href);

    }
   );   
}
});
```

If I run this code in the console using node it retrieves all the hrefs and corresponding text, but when I bundle it using browserify and try with the browser it throws cannot fetch absolute path error

here's the complete error in browser console

Fetch API cannot load chrome-extension://url. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS

here's the link to the images of the console and the line throwing error in concern

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3X0Q.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3znR.png

Comment: Please post the code here, instead of hiding it in a picture behind a link.  And how does someone fairly new to javascript end up with a 27k line source file?

Comment: @Teepeemm The 27k source file is not suprising considering the fact that he uses browserify.

Comment: thank you for your comments, found a solution not requiring node